# Shall I consider a text response to an email as official one for leave request?

Tags: communication, email, unprofessional-behavior, time-off

I sent my boss an email regarding personal issues I was having inside and outside of work, and I stated I wanted to use personal time off I had accumulated.

Within the email, I also stated I would reach out to coworkers to help find coverage for the three days I had asked for off.

Instead of them responding back via email stating wether or not the days off would be approved or not, boss sent me a short text message only saying not to reach out to coworkers for coverage, they’d take care of it.

No questions I had within the email were answered nor did I get an actually approval for the time off. I’m wondering if the situation was handled appropriately and if it’s totally normal for a boss to text a short response back rather than answering on top of my actual email?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? As it stands now, this post does not really have a question in it. Are you wondering how to respond? Whether this was appropriate? I think it will be difficult to even answer those questions without more context, would you be able to expand your post with more details and a clearer question?

Comment: Just edited my post!

Comment: Your boss was out and about, or busy, and wanted to address the most pressing thing, you trying to doing their job and confuse matters. Maybe they'll send a follow up email later.

Comment: If you're not sure you could ask (via e-mail if you prefer), "got your SMS; as for taking days X and Y off, do I have your OK?" If you focus on just one question then it's more likely to get just the answer to that one.

Comment: I updated the question to be more to-the-point. Feel free to revert if something is off.

Answer (score 6):

The way I see it, if someone is saying they'll take care to cover for the days of your absence, that indicates they are aware are okay with your absence. Also since they're in the approver position, this indicates they approve your absence.

Most likely, they wanted a quick communication (they don't know if you're still checking emails or not), so they sent the text. If you're skeptical, please respond to your email, thanking them for confirming the leave over text and agreeing to cover for your absence.

Answer (score 5):

Your boss is doing damage control, he does not want you talking to your colleagues about needing leave as you're having issues at work. So he texted quickly to pre-empt that potential.

The rest needs clarification only he can give you, but the implication is that you'll get your three days.

Answer (score 1):

It's not abnormal, though it's probably less common.

If you think the response was unclear (though I think "I'll take care of it" implies authorization), reply to your boss asking for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Send him another email quoting his text message with the endorsement "As per your text message of  ..." and say that you will follow and rely on his instructions.